# Android app size increased after adding admob ads using google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, admob, proguard

I'm gonna publishing my app in two versions, both paid and free (with AdMob ads).
The two versions are exactly identical except for the google-play-service_lib that i use in the free version for AdMob services.

The final apk sizes after using proguard are:
1.301.435 bytes for paid version
1.946.634 bytes for ads version

In free version i show interstitial ads only.

Here's my proguard settings relative to the google-play-service_lib

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Is there something i can do to reduce file size like removing some -keep flags or what?

**EDIT**

Using [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) i discovered that none of the classes from the Google Play Service package has been shrinked (including `com.google.android.gms.maps.*`, `com.google.android.gms.games.*` and many others that i think are not needed for Ads management).

How to force shrink a class or a class group?

**EDIT (again)**

It looks like Eclipse doesn't keep Proguard output, at least i couldn't see it anywhere. I then configured my projects and libs to be build using Ant to see some output, but it's almost unsubstantial, these are two cases:

```
 -whyareyoukeeping class com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap

 [proguard] Explaining why classes and class members are being kept...
 [proguard] Printing usage to [...../bin/proguard/usage.txt]...
 [proguard] com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
 [proguard]   is not being kept.
```

(at least i read that class is not been kept, although i can see it using apktool!) and

```
 -whyareyoukeeping class com.google.android.gms.games.Games

 [proguard] Explaining why classes and class members are being kept...
 [proguard] Printing usage to [...../bin/proguard/usage.txt]...
```

here nothing is said about given class.

I'm giving up, for a single interstitial my app increases his size by 50%, although [Google about GPS](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) states:

> The client library has a light footprint if you use ProGuard as part
>   of your build process, so it won't have an adverse impact on your
>   app's file size.

and no-where i could find a guide for it!

Comment: Not a real solution, just something that might help: You can probably remove the drawable-XXXX folders. They only contain sign-in/out & +1 button images. I would check the library license to verify that's OK with Google.

Comment: @sagis +1! Thanx, this is an interesting point.

Answer (score 13):

it is nothing to do with proguard.
as you know, google play service is close source. proguard can't handle it without source 
code. but you can shrink it manually.

1, remove unused class from jar file

in the folder of google play service, typically sdk\extras\google\google_play_services
\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\,
open **google-play-services.jar** with zip file manager such as 7zip, you can find many 
folder such as maps, games and so on witch is no use for you if you only use ads. so just
delete them. be careful to keep **ads, common, dynamic, internal** and **location** folder otherwise you will get fc of NoClassDefFoundError when show ads.

2, remove unused resource from res folder if you only use ads.

many resource in google-play-services_lib\res folder is no use for you, you can remove it. such as values-af, values-am, .... what you need to keep is **color, drawable, drawable-hdpi** and **values** folder.

3, now refresh and build the google-play-services_lib project in your eclipse, then refresh 
and build your project again. now you shold find the apk size get smaller. the size of my 
apk go down from **902kb** to **480kb** before proguard, and **330kb** after proguard.

Comment: Are you sure proguard can't handle JAR files without source code? I think it is using only .class files not .java files.

Comment: Good solution, recommended and working. Much quicker than setting up Gradle for dependency or multi-dex.

Comment: This results in  com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode) does not match path (google-play-services/com/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode.class). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

did u use this line in your build.gradle file?

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

if yes then supplement it with this line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.+'
```

It reduces the app size by around 600kb.

Answer (score 2):

Some other part of your proguard config is causing the GPS classes to be retained.

Have a look at [Proguard Usage](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html) especially the option

> -whyareyoukeeping class_specification

You can use that to tell uyou why particualr classes are being kept if you can't spot it yourself.

Comment: thanx, i'll have a look.

Comment: Now my question is: how to know what are the kept classes i actually don't need?

Comment: You need to specifically retain any classes that might be constructed via reflection. Ie Activities or other classes referenced from XML. The remainder can be worked out by Proguard as it creates it's dependency graph.

Comment: Well, i just need AdMob interstitials ads to be shown, don't use any XML for it. I imported com.google.android.gms.ads.* into my code, nothing else.

Comment: I tried using proguard with -whyareyoukeeping class com.google..android.gsm.*... from eclipse->file->export, where can i find the output? Consoles are showing nothing new...

Comment: Sorry I don't use Eclipse. But when you run Proguard it generates output (besides the obfuscated classes). Look in wherever Eclipse is putting build output and read the Proguard doco.

Comment: I edited my question, -whyareyoukeeping didn't help, it doesn't seem to say anything useful...

Comment: As I don't need anything but com.google.android.gms.ads.**. I ignore all files including drawable stuff from Google Play Services. Is this correct? because it looks fine for me.