# how to reduce app size increased after admob ads?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, proguard

before adding google-play-services to my project its size was just **900kb** and after adding lib of play services it is now **4.01MB**. its terrible. for 900kb app ads of 3MB is too much.

help me as soon as possible. my app is finished now.

I tried reading about **proguard** but unable to understand. someone please give me step by step tutorial to reduce app size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to edit google-play-services.jar file. Use proguard to keep only needed class files.

Create proguard.txt file in your module directory (e.g. app/) and write following lines in that file:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
    public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
    public *;
}

-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Now write following lines in your module's build.gradle file (for e.g. app/build.gradle):

```
...
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.txt'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.txt'
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Sync your gradle file and build & run your app. Now see the difference in size of your app.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not distributing your app outside Google Play, you can take a look at Lite version of Google Mobile Ads SDK

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/lite-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555662/android-app-size-increased-after-adding-admob-ads-using-google-play-services-lib)

The library for Google play service is located at

```
SDK_PATH\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs
```

After editing the jar, put it in the libs folder of your app.

Add the depencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

In the manifest you need to specify the version

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
      android:value="#####" />
```

The version number can be found in the manifest file in the folder indicated above

Example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:versionCode="5089000" 
     android:versionName="5.0.89-000" package="com.google.android.gms">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
    <application/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app.

I tested. It really works. We MUST to do this to reduce APK size. :)

And do you use Android Studio? I don't know how to do this on Eclipse.

Check this [document](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project).