# why admob increases size of my app 5mb?

Tags: android-studio, admob

I am using android studio.I follwed these steps https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

After added admobs my app size increased almost 5mb.it was 13mb after became 18mb.

Comment: Library is large because its the whole play services. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978356/how-to-reduce-app-size-increased-after-admob-ads for some advice

Comment: i have this code compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0' in my app/build.gradle doesn't this mean my app uses only ads part of service?

Comment: it works thank you.But how? what changed now?

Comment: It must have removed a lot of the extra junk, those libraries are full of extra stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Implies you are using every feature of Google Play Services, including location services. If you only need a particular API, you should be using the [selective APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).

In the case of ads, you can use solely:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at [how to reduce app size increased after admob ads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978356/how-to-reduce-app-size-increased-after-admob-ads)

Simply put: The library has a lot of extra stuff. You need to use ProGuard to strip that out.