# what is the effect of APK file size if Admob is integrated?

Tags: android, admob, proguard

We added Admob in our live-wallpaper project and its size almost increased from 2 Mb - 4 Mb. we are so much concerned about file size, we are using pro-guard too. Are we doing it wrong or is this just normal? Also is it necessary to add google play service library for integrating admob, is there anyway to avoid it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901391/why-admob-increases-size-of-my-app-5mb

Answer (score 0):

Adding AdMob to an android project takes up only few lines of code. Hence, this cannot be the reason of your app size getting increased.

Have you tried removing AdMob and rechecking the new size?

Comment: Adding Admob is just a few lines, but we are adding google play services library to the project.

Answer (score 0):

It simply depends on the size of google-play-services size which you are using, different version different size, which may also differs from IDE to IDE for android developement.

Instead of the complete library import, use it in build.gradle file :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.+'
```

It reduces the app size by around 600kb.

Comment: Using google play services library and according to the google document.

Comment: check my answer, and also tell me about you current apk size with admob and without any admob and without google play services

Comment: I am using eclipse, how to do use gradle there?

Comment: Then go for Android studio, otherwise search for small size library as suits to you

Comment: I am updating apps after long time, Android studio is better than eclipse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96456/discussion-between-androider-and-unitedartinc).