# Android Admob : Is there any violation to remove resources from google play services SDK

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

With Admob SDK my apk size was **680KB**. When replaced Admob SDK with `google play services SDK` it is **1.3MB**.(with **[Proguard](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard)**)

As Suggested by **@daniel** in [Android app size increased after adding admob ads using google-play-services_lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276702/991085) (Did second step)

> 2, remove unused resource from res folder if you only use ads.
>
> many resource in google-play-services_lib\res folder is no use for
>   you, you can remove it. such as values-af, values-am, .... what you
>   need to keep is **color, drawable, drawable-hdpi** and **values**
>   folder.

I removed resources from **google-play-services_lib** such as `values-af, values-am, ....` and keep **color, drawable, drawable-hdpi** and **values** folder.Then my apk size is **890KB**

I haven't use this on production yet, and I don't know if this could be against **Google Play Services TOS**. But it's the only way I've found to reduce the size of the app after adding Google Play Services.

I want to use only **Admob Ads** service,So **Is it Ok to edit `google play services SDK` in this way to reduce apk size and would my solution violate Google Play Services TOS**?

As I am afraid from this [Admob Account Disabled After Implementation : Publisher Guide](http://bigknol.com/admob-account-disabled-after-implementation/)

> ## 9 Do not modify Adunit
>
> You have only limited modification over ads so make sure that you
>   haven’t altered native features of Admob (Google Play Store Services)
>   SDK. Publishers cannot be shared source of Google SDK code or library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your app. You can pick and choose what to include or not.

As far as I am aware there is no requirement to ship the entire Google Play Services library. Since you can use Proguard to whittle it down there really couldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove unnecessary packages from the google play services library using proguard in android studio.

My app was also only about 2 Mb. When I included google play services library for AdMob integration it became 6 Mb. So I did the following steps to maintain the size.

In your projects module folder add a file named 'proguard.txt' and use the following code

```
# Keep all public mobile ads classes.
# Keep all public mobile ads classes.
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
*;
}
# For mediation
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
*;
}
```

copy the same in \tools\proguard if you want in build mode also

configure your build.gradle as follows

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release{
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

now sync the gradle with the project with sync icon 
build and run the project to see change